# Mails sent to mail server with no MX record

Tags: nameserver, mx-record

We updated a nameserver for one of our clients domains only to find out later that he already had mails set up a different nameserver (the one we were asked to replace).

For the period it was changed, his mails were getting routed to our DNS which did not have an MX record in it. Is there any way of recovering mails that were sent during this time? What will his recipients have seen?

Will there be a log anywhere of these mails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the absence of an MX record, mail is routed to the A record entry for that FQDN. So the only way you can recover the messages or get a log is if the system and network the A record points to is configured to process email inbound from the internet.

Otherwise, chances are you're hard out luck; maybe someone else will chime in with something more useful.

Comment: This is correct.  If there was a mailserver at an A record configured to process mail for the domain, then it could be there.  Otherwise, the sender would get a NDR from their mailserver.